# How can I make sure my guard statement doesn't proceed with a nil value?

Tags: ios, swift

I've been trying to implement a guard statement and I think I have the implementation correct except my code runs past the guard statement even when I pass in nil values. I basically keep the fields empty and hit a register button to run this piece of code, but it assigns empty values to email and password, and the code runs right past the "else" block. Some help would be appreciated.

```
    guard let email = emailField.text, let password = passwordField.text, let name = nameField.text else {
        print ("FYF: Form is not valid")
        return
    }

    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!)
            return
        }
```

I used a breakpoint at the guard statement and stepped over it. When I checked the variables inspector it says the email and password field are nil. I think I may have implemented something wrong. Thank you!

Comment: How have you declared your `UITextField` variables?

Comment: @TristanBeaton I'm not using any UILabel's, just UITextFields. And I did declare those earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct and probably never will enter the guard clause. Here you are setting values of variables base on, I think, UIText fields. This fields when empty are not null. It's important to understand that an empty string is not the same thing as a null value. An empty string, represented as "" is still a string. A null value is, like JavaScript coders like to talk: has an undefined type. Your guard clause will fail only when you try to set a non nil property to nil value.

To solve this, you just change your guard clause to something like:

```
guard emailField.text.isEmpty == false, passwordField.text.isEmpty == false
```

Or

```
guard !emailField.text.isEmpty, !passwordField.text.isEmpty
```

Comment: Worth noting also when coding for iOS 10 or later, UITextField conforms to UITextInput which inherits from UIKeyInput which has an instance property specific for that called hasText https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext. `guard emailField.hasText, passwordField.hasText else`

Answer (score 0):

`UITextfield` returns empty string `""` by default if no text is entered. So your guard statement will always be true.

Check if `UITextfield` isn't empty instead of nil e.g.

```
    guard let email = (emailField.text?.isEmpty == false ? tfTest1.text : nil) else {
        print ("FYF: Form is not valid")
        return
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Yes, I just saw it now. I added a different example code to do it, you can use either. Thanks!